# Backup Project Hamster Data

Tags: backup, productivity

I'd like to move my [project hamster time tracking](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster) data from one PC to another. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 23):

**hamster** database is in `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db`.

The best way to keep it synced is by moving the file to the Ubuntu cloud or Dropbox folder and then *symlinking* it back to where it was on all the boxes. hamster is watching for file changes and following symlinks so this way you can have same hamster database on several computers.

Comment: Though for a backup as the question implies, redundancy is *desired* so symlinking would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 3):

(I am assuming that you are moving to a computer running Linux, and that you have not used Hamster on that computer before) Open your Home folder, press 'control + h' to show hidden files. Open .local > share, copy the 'hamster-applet' folder and paste it in the .local/share/ folder on your other computer.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my hamster DB on Dropbox and make a symlink named:

`~/.local/share/hamster-applet` (where hamster searches for the `hamster.db` file)

So the symlink points to my dropbox folder where I keep the backed up `hamster.db`

Answer (score 1):

I have used hamster in Ubuntu 16.04.
After system update on Ubuntu 20.04 I have installed hamster-snap package.
But snap packages use independent separate folder to keep settings, and when I have runned hamster-snap there was no my tracking time history.

So I have closed hamster application. Have found where is old and new hamster.db, and have replace new hamster.db by my old hamster.db.
Then I have runned hamster-snap application with my tracking time history.

```
find ~ -name hamster.db
/home/user/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db
/home/user/snap/hamster-snap/47/.local/share/hamster/hamster.db

cp ~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db
~/snap/hamster-snap/47/.local/share/hamster/hamster.db
```